# animating html5 drag and drop while dropping an element

Tags: html, css, animation

I am using native HTML5 drag and drop for a simple game application where user needs to drag the images of animals and place in to the correct bays (domestic /wild). When I am dropping (appending) the dragged element to the bay, I want to animate it and make it appear as if the elements are flying and getting dropped in the bay.

I have tried `fadeIn()`, but it happens after the element has been appended. I need the animation between the dragstart and the drop. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do mean by flying into it.  Doesn't the element move with the mouse cursor or finger?

Answer (score 2):

For what you are trying to achieve html5 drag'n'drop functionality might not be the best for precise visual experience you are looking.

As default behaviour slightly differs in browsers and most annoying is 'move back animation' once dragged item is dropped.
I have no idea why developers behind Chrome did that stupid "feature" that even delays the `dragend` event, which is even worse thing..

So you would need to write your own drag'n'drop functionality with very precise visual functionality, but I would not recommend using html5 drag'n'drop for your particular case.